# Rails 3: Mongoid::Errors::NoSessionsConfig

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, mongoid, database

I'm unable to use `mongoid` in production mode in my rails application. I'm using **Rails 3.2.14** and **mongoid 3.0.23**

```
Mongoid::Errors::NoSessionsConfig (
Problem:
  No sessions configuration provided.
Summary:
  Mongoid's configuration requires that you provide details about each session that can be connected to, and requires in the sessions config at least 1 default session to exist.
Resolution:
  Double check your mongoid.yml to make sure that you have a top-level sessions key with at least 1 default session configuration for it. You can regenerate a new mongoid.yml for assistance via `rails g mongoid:config`.

 Example:
   development:
     sessions:
       default:
         database: mongoid_dev
         hosts:
           - localhost:27017

):
```

Everything works fine in developement mode. Here's the **mongoid.yml**.

```
production:
  sessions:
    default:
      database: myapp_production
      hosts:
        - localhost:27027
      username: username
      password: password
  options:
    raise_not_found_error: false
    use_activesupport_time_zone: true
    identity_map_enabled: true

development:
  # Configure available database sessions. (required)
  sessions:
    # Defines the default session. (required)
    default:
      # Defines the name of the default database that Mongoid can connect to.
      # (required).
      database: myapp_development
      # Provides the hosts the default session can connect to. Must be an array
      # of host:port pairs. (required)
      hosts:
        - localhost:27017

test:
  sessions:
    default:
      database: chanderi_test
      hosts:
        - localhost:27017
      options:
        consistency: :strong
        # In the test environment we lower the retries and retry interval to
        # low amounts for fast failures.
        max_retries: 1
        retry_interval: 0
```

How should I set up the database?

Answer (score 0):

In your mongoid.yml in development section you have `Mongoid specific options` as empty, if you want to put some options then paste it after `options:` otherwise remove this line as due to that it is not able to detect test environment and giving error. Your mongoid.yml should be like this

```
production:
  sessions:
    default:
      database: myapp_production
      hosts:
        - localhost:27027
      username: username
      password: password
  options:
    raise_not_found_error: false
    use_activesupport_time_zone: true
    identity_map_enabled: true

development:
  # Configure available database sessions. (required)
  sessions:
    # Defines the default session. (required)
    default:
      # Defines the name of the default database that Mongoid can connect to.
      # (required).
      database: myapp_development
      # Provides the hosts the default session can connect to. Must be an array
      # of host:port pairs. (required)
      hosts:
        - localhost:27017

test:
  sessions:
    default:
      database: chanderi_test
      hosts:
        - localhost:27017
      options:
        consistency: :strong
        # In the test environment we lower the retries and retry interval to
        # low amounts for fast failures.
        max_retries: 1
        retry_interval: 0
```

Comment: it still gives the same error. I even tried removing the options from all of the environment configuration. check the updated `mongoid.yml` now